# Turtlebot Navigation using simulated turtlebot in gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-hydro, turtlebot-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to navigate simulated Turtlebot in gazebo. All tutorials in ros are for real robot. I have already launched turtlebot using

**roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch**

Now, I am trying to launch 3Dsensors using

**roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch**

but its giving

started roslaunch server

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /camera/camera_nodelet_manager/num_worker_threads
- /camera/depth_rectify_depth/interpolation
- /camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth/interpolation
- /camera/disparity_depth/max_range
- /camera/disparity_depth/min_range
- /camera/disparity_registered_hw/max_range
- /camera/disparity_registered_hw/min_range
- /camera/disparity_registered_sw/max_range
- /camera/disparity_registered_sw/min_range
- /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url
- /camera/driver/depth_frame_id
- /camera/driver/depth_registration
- /camera/driver/device_id
- /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url
- /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id
- /depthimage_to_laserscan/output_frame_id
- /depthimage_to_laserscan/range_min
- /depthimage_to_laserscan/scan_height
- /rosdistro
- /rosversion

NODES
/camera/
camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_points (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_registered_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
disparity_registered_hw (nodelet/nodelet)
disparity_registered_sw (nodelet/nodelet)
driver (nodelet/nodelet)
points_xyzrgb_hw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
points_xyzrgb_sw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet)
rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)
register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
/
depthimage_to_laserscan (nodelet/nodelet)

ROS_MASTER_URI= http :// localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [3976]
process[camera/driver-2]: started with pid [3990]
[ INFO] [1386425317.398225356]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
process[camera/debayer-3]: started with pid [4030]
process[camera/rectify_mono-4]: started with pid [4046]
process[camera/rectify_color-5]: started with pid [4062]
process[camera/rectify_ir-6]: started with pid [4078]
[ INFO] [1386425317.836443133, 24.650000000]: **No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected**
process[camera/depth_rectify_depth-7]: started with pid [4094]
process[camera/depth_metric_rect-8]: started with pid [4110]
process[camera/depth_metric-9]: started with pid [4126]
process[camera/depth_points-10]: started with pid [4142]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-11]: started with pid [4158]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12]: started with pid [4174]
process[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-13]: started with pid [4190]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-14]: started with pid [4206]
process[camera/disparity_depth-15]: started with pid [4222]
process[camera/disparity_registered_sw-16]: started with pid [4238]
process[camera/disparity_registered_hw-17]: started with pid [4254]
process[depthimage_to_laserscan-18]: started with pid [4270]
[ INFO] [1386425320.843662829, 27.670000000]: **No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected**
[ INFO] [1386425323.847297153, 30.670000000]: **No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected**
[ INFO] [1386425326.853849462, 33.680000000]: **No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected**

what should I do to connect it with simulated turtlebot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107911/turtlebot-navigation-using-simulated-turtlebot-in-gazebo??/) by [DPK27](https://answers.ros.org/users/9621/dpk27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-12-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RD](https://answers.ros.org/users/9881/rd/) on 2013-12-13**:
I am having the same problem. Did you find the solution?

**Comment by [DPK27](https://answers.ros.org/users/9621/dpk27/) on 2013-12-14**:
without launching 3D sensor, by just launching the rviz after turtlebot using
"roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_robot.launch"
and selecting laser or point cloud you can see the obstacle in front.
So, as I think there is no need of 3dsensor.launch for me, see if it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The turtlebot simulator wont work on groovy. Some people have managed to get it work with tweaks. From the ros wiki only compatibility is with electric, fuerte and hydro at the moment.  I would suggest looking into the hector_turtlebot package, that will work with the groovy. They have a hector_gazebo_simulation for running turtlebot with a hokuyo laser.

---

Originally posted by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) with karma: 340 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DPK27](https://answers.ros.org/users/9621/dpk27/) on 2013-12-14**:
I am using hydro only.

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2013-12-14**:
Have you installed the turtlebot package along with the simulator?